# reference error but day has been defined. please indicate what im doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, express

when I'm logging day I'm getting the expected result. The webpage still functions properly even after getting the error though

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  let day = date.getDate();
  
  console.log(day);
  
  res.render("list", { date: day, listTitle: "Today", newListItems: docs});
    
  });
```

```html
<div class="date-time">
    <p><%=date%></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not enough information, but a rough guess: transform `day` into a string.

Comment: When reporting errors please post the *exact* error, and include relevant details like how have you configured your view engine, the name of the file with the HTML in it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this Hope it helps

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  var date = new Date();
  let day = date.getDate();

  console.log(day);

  res.render("list", { date: day, listTitle: "Today", newListItems: docs});

  });
```

```html
<div class="date-time">
    <p><%=date%></p>
  </div>
```